# Manage local state inside render props function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to pass a render prop to a third party library. But I want to have an internal state inside the render prop function. For instance, let's say I want to toggle the opacity of the render prop.

If this was a **function component** I'd use hooks (seen in the comments on the code below), but I don't know how to handle state for each item on the list.

What should I do to make the toggle work?

```
// Third party I can't change.
function ThirdParty({ render, items }) {
  return items.map(i => render(i));
}

// My render prop.
function renderProp(val) {
  // const [toggle, setToggle] = React.useState(false);
  function handleClick() {
    console.log("not toggling");
    // setToggle(prev => !prev);
  }
  // const opacity = toggle ? 1 : 0;
  const opacity = 1;
  return (
    <div key={val} style={{ display: "flex", opacity }}>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>toggle</button>
      <div>Item {val}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThirdParty render={renderProp} items={[1, 2, 3]} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Running example: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-wood-xklyi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use hooks if you capitalize the name of the function `renderProp`.

Modified codepen for demonstration: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-chandrasekhar-4p0fd

renderProp is a component so it should be exported as capitalized `RenderProp`

Comment: It's working with the codesandbox, although with my real case, it doesn't fix it.  But I can't replicate the issue. I'm going to consider it answered and try to find a solution with the guys that created the library. Thanks.

Comment: It's working with render={props=> <RenderProps {...props}/> } but I'd prefer not to have to wrap a render prop function around the function component like in your example.

Comment: Cool, glad to help! Good luck